# Mat Slider Value in Angular 15

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular15

The code used to work in Angular 14 but is not working in Angular 15.

```
    <mat-slider
            min="1"
            max="150"
            step="10"
            value="55"
            #itemHeight
     >
     </mat-slider>

     <label> {{ itemHeight.value  }} hie </label>
```

StackBlitz link => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixbgdr?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now have to pass an input to the slider :

```
  <mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5">
     <input matSliderThumb #itemHeight>
  </mat-slider>

  <label>  {{itemHeight.value}} </label>
```

Comment: Thanks, working now.
I was trying the input but was not giving the id to it.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes are clearly outlined in the MDC migration guide - [MDC Migration Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#slider)

You would have found your answer also from the docs for the slider component - [Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview)